# How can I pass a ListView from MainPage to other xaml page?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a simple Windows Phone app (XAML and C#).
In the MainPage  I have a ListView Control filled with string items that is need to be passed to other xaml page.

So can I somehow pass the whole ListView to the other page or need to cast ListView items to List container first and then pass the List to other xaml page?

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

Can I use this function to do the tick?

Comment: You should not push the ListView to another controll. Insted push the Data that is shown inside your View to your new View and repopulate the List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MainPage pass the string object as parameter to your next page.

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(NextPage), objString);
```

On your second page now you can get the object as List

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var ListItem = e.Parameter as List<string>;
        SampleListView.ItemsSource = ListItem;
    }
```

Now you can bind the object as the ItemsSource of your ListView.